# how do I make an onclick perform two functions: show description and show video or picture

Tags: jquery, buttonclick

I am trying to figure out a way to click a button that will show a subsequant div.  and then also show a related video.

I need it to be scalable so that anything I add will automatically incorporate itself into the process.

here is the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HSNrf/

Jquery

```
var $class = $('#vtab>div>h3');

$class.click(function(){
    $('#vtab>div>div').toggle();
    $('iframe').toggle();
});

$class.hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="vtab">
    <div class="classes">
         <h3>Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>First Cool video</div>
         <h3>Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>second cool video</div>
         <h3>Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>third cool video</div>
         <h3>Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>forth cool video</div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="vid1"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid2"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid3"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid4"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#vtab{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#vtab div > h3{
    background: #990099; /* Old browsers */
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:2px 0;
    font-size:22px;
  font-weight:bold;
  list-style:none;
  margin:2px 8px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:#333333 0 -1px 0;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:5px;
  width:220px;    
}

.classes{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
}

.video{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

iframe{
     width:230px;
    margin:50px;
}
```

my ultimate goal is to add 10 to 30 videos this way.  When the button is pushed I only want it to show one video.  Right now the code gets rid of all the descriptions and all the videos.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $headings = $('#vtab > div > h3'),
    $iframe = $('.video iframe'),
    $divs = $('#vtab > div > div');

$headings.click(function() {
    // index of clicked element in jQuery Collection($headings)
    var ind = $headings.index(this);
    // filtering target elements according to the index
    $divs.hide().eq(ind).show();
    $iframe.hide().eq(ind).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks I went with this model :-)  I added the var 
"}).eq(0).click();" at the bottom so the first one would be selcted

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a way to associate the `<h3>` element to the `<div>` containing the description and the `<iframe>` (that I assume has the video). The first part is easy - it's just the next element. The second part would best be achieved using a `data-*` attribute that links the `<h3>` to a particular `<iframe>`.

Your HTML would become:

```
<div id="vtab">
    <div class="classes">
         <h3 data-video="vid1">Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>First Cool video</div>
         <h3 data-video="vid2">Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>second cool video</div>
         <h3 data-video="vid3">Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>third cool video</div>
         <h3 data-video="vid4">Welcome Home!</h3>
            <div>forth cool video</div>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe class="vid1"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid2"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid3"></iframe>
        <iframe class="vid4"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your code would become:

```
var $class = $('#vtab>div>h3');

$class.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); // this is the specific h3 you just clicked on
    $this.next().toggle(); // the .next() function gets the next element
    var video = $this.attr('data-video');
    $('.' + video).toggle();
});

$class.hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

It might also make sense to change the class on the `<iframe>` elements to an `id` instead, since they're intended to uniquely identify the videos. If you did do that, you'd change the `'.' + video` to `'#' + video` in the code above.

Comment: AWESOME!  thanks!  i just read up on the .next and was playing around with that.  Let me make your suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  i am trying to learn this stuff :-)